# how to remove CDATA from particular field in xml using shell script

Tags: xml, shell

I have below content in xml file. I want to remove CDATA using shell script from particular field "ute.sourceSystem".

```
<RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="customerType_Support">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[regular]]></PVAL>
        </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="ute.sourceSystem">
        <PVAL>
            <![CDATA[cms]]>
        </PVAL>
    </PROP>
</RECORD>
```

expected output -

```
<RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="customerType_Support">
            <PVAL><![CDATA[regular]]></PVAL>
        </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="ute.sourceSystem">
        <PVAL>
            <cms>
        </PVAL>
    </PROP>
</RECORD>
```

Comment: The output isn't valid XML, you realize?

Answer (score 1):

CDATA sections in XML are just a syntactic feature. Semantically, the XML is equivalent to

```
<RECORD>
    <PROP NAME="customerType_Support">
            <PVAL>regular</PVAL>
        </PROP>
    <PROP NAME="ute.sourceSystem">
        <PVAL>
            cms
        </PVAL>
    </PROP>
</RECORD>
```

To replace the text by an element, you can use e.g. [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
insert element normalize-space(/RECORD/PROP[@NAME="ute.sourceSystem"]/PVAL)
    into /RECORD/PROP[@NAME="ute.sourceSystem"]/PVAL ;
delete /RECORD/PROP[@NAME="ute.sourceSystem"]/PVAL/text() ;
save :b ;
```

Note that it inserts `<cms/>`, not `<cms>`, as it would have created an ill-formed XML.

Comment: Thank you!. can we do the same using sed or awk command? as i need to install above plugin to do this.

Comment: `sed` and `awk` aren't XML-aware so they can easily break the data.